# How does javascript function call work?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code below:
It makes a GET call to an URL, gets some object, and appends an image to an HTML tag.

```
function getDataFromApi(searchTerm, callback) {
  const URL1 = `some url`;

  const design = {
    url: URL1,
    data: {
      "dog breed name": searchTerm
    },
    type: 'GET',
    success: callback
  };
  $.ajax(design);
}

function displaySearchData(data) {
  const allResultsLength = data.message.length;
  const ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * allResultsLength);
  const dogResults = data.message[ranNum];
  $(`.js-search-results`).html(`<img src = ${dogResults}>`);
}

function watchSubmit() {
  $('.js-search-form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let queryTarget = $(event.currentTarget).find('.js-query');
    let query = queryTarget.val();
    queryTarget.val("");
    getDataFromApi(query, displaySearchData);
  });
}

$(watchSubmit);
```

I get the `getDataFromApi` and `watchSubmit` but `getDataFromApi(query, displaySearchData);` isn't intuitive to me at all.
I've been writing Java, and it doesn't make sense to me how `displaySearchData` is getting called without the parameter - it seems that line should be `getDataFromApi(query, displaySearchData(data));`.

Can someone please explain how this is getting compiled & executed (basically how this is a legitimate syntax) in javascript?

Comment: Well, `displaySearchData` is getting called at `success: callback` in your API.. You are passing a `function` to `another function` here, and letting the `another function` do whatever it wants with it

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed I think that's the part I don't understand about javascript.. so if it's getting called as a callback, then you don't need a parameter?

Comment: In this case, callback is a function, the function you passed. Now, you are again passing it to the `success` key of the `$.ajax`. Now it's upto `$.ajax` to call the function when ever it wants. It also can give params to the function.

Comment: This kind of programming style allows for you to have async nature.. sort of saying like: `when you are done with getting the data from AJAX, this is the function you'll execute - pass it whatever you want, I'll handle it`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed so if I didn't have $.ajax, will I need something to pass into `displaySearchData`?

Comment: Yeah, let's say you don't have an AJAX call, then, to call the `displaySearchData` you just do - `displaySearchData({data: 'here'})`

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed Thanks for the help :D

Comment: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/ is a really good article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the good'ol jquery, there lies this piece of code:

```
$.ajax = function(config){
    ...
    // get the response from XHR request, 
    // and save it in, say, 'response'
    ...
    // now check, if the response is OK 200 
    // and if so, execute next line
    // which is basically - calling your displaySearchData method
    config.success(response);
    ...
}
```

now, `config` is your `design` object, which has a property `success` which carries the reference to your `displaySearchData` method.

The `data` argument of method `displaySearchData` will now carry the reference to variable `response` passed in the method invocation `config.success(response)`.

**EDIT:** the argument `callback` also carries forward the reference of the method `displaySearchData` to `getDataFromApi`

**Concept to be noted:**

functions can be passed in Javascript as arguments to another function, in which case we only need the referring variable to be passed as argument. Invocation parentheses `()` are not required.

```
function A(data){...};

function b(referenceToFunctionA){
    ...
    referenceToFunctionA(someData);
    ...
}; 
// correct
b(A);

// wrong, because adding () after any function reference variable
// invokes the method immediately.
// in this particular case the returned value of the method A
// is passed as argument instead of the reference to method A itself.
b(A());
```

Welcome to JavaScript My Friend. Get ready to experience more magical weirdness as you continue to work on JS. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look at is in the function getDataFromApi().

In that function, you have a "callback" parameter. This parameter is later added into $.ajax. This is a jQuery function that will provide some callback when a certain condition is matched (like before sending a request, when the response has been received,...). This $.ajax callback provide you with 3 parameters, one of them is data (which are being used, textStatus, and jqXHR. Usually, you only need to pay attention to the data since it contains the response from where you are requesting data.

So when the $.ajax success, the "callback" function will be called, which is the displaySearchData. And since $.ajax callback provides you with the data parameter, you can add them to the parameters of displaySearchData. Do note that you can add the extra 2 provided parameters if needed.

You can have a look at that function here: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)